# Open Document returns error (SOFFICEINTEGRATION)

Tags: abap

I'm trying to open a Excel file with SOFFICEINTEGRATION to modify the file inplace.

But I always get the CALL_NOT_FLUSHED error, I tried several code snippets (with no_flush = X and no_flush = ' ')

The error "CALL_NOT_FLUSHED" is appearing after calling proxy->open_document

My current code:

```
DATA proxy TYPE REF TO i_oi_document_proxy.

PARAMETERS dummy.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF proxy IS NOT BOUND.
    CALL METHOD c_oi_container_control_creator=>get_container_control
      IMPORTING
        control = DATA(lo_container_control)
        retcode = DATA(l_rc).

    CALL METHOD lo_container_control->init_control
      EXPORTING
        r3_application_name      = 'EXCEL' "#EC NOTEXT
        inplace_enabled          = 'X'
        inplace_scroll_documents = 'X'
        parent                   = cl_gui_container=>screen0
      IMPORTING
        retcode                  = l_rc.

    CALL METHOD lo_container_control->get_document_proxy
      EXPORTING
        document_type  = 'EXCEL.SHEET'
      IMPORTING
        document_proxy = proxy.

    CALL METHOD proxy->open_document
      EXPORTING
        document_url = 'file://C:\Users\yourusername\Documents\test.xlsx'
        open_inplace = 'X'
      IMPORTING
        error        = DATA(openerr).
  ENDIF.
```

Comment: Maybe using `document_url = 'file://...'` is a problem? (although the documentation says "URLs of documents in the local file system must be prefaced with 'file://'."). What about loading the Excel file yourself, and use the method `OPEN_DOCUMENT_FROM_TABLE`?

Comment: I did a test. No issue at my side. Try with the latest SAP GUI version, and verify the SAP Support Web site. Contact SAP Support if you don't find any applicable patch. NB: I updated the code in your question so that to make it a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (just change the path to an existing Excel file).

Comment: @LoopAt Maybe your Office is not installed, installed incorrectly or corrupted? Try the above code on another PC with fresh SAPGui and fresh Office

Comment: @SandraRossi the path is correct, but I decided to use OPEN_INPLACE = FALSE, because it seems to have problems with opening the Excel inside SAP

Comment: @LoopAt Could you post your solution `OPEN_INPLACE = abap_false` as an answer so that to help future visitors? Thank you!